# Subsetting points by Drawing Circles around points

Tags: r

I have 6000 geocoded points of TB cases for NYC.  I want to subset my data by drawing circles around each point of a certain radius. Basically, I would subset the data 6000 times around each point using distance.
How can I do that?
This is an example of the coordinates of the points. For example, I want to select case 1 and only only select cases that are within 1000 feet radius of this case 1. Then I want to do the same for case2  and so on. Eventually I should end up 6000 subset of the data.

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example of your data, and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `dist()` function to calculate the Euclidean distances between all the rows of data.  Then, for each row of the resulting distance matrix, you could subset the data that meet your radius criterion.  For example:

```
# some fake data, as a matrix
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
m <- cbind(x, y)

# distances among each row of m
d <- dist(cbind(x, y))

# maximum distance cut off
radius <- 1

# subsets of m within cut off distance of each point, a list of matrices
subsets <- apply(as.matrix(d) < radius, 1, function(i) cbind(x, y)[i, ])
```